# Are there IDEs that automatically create onClick function. Besides Embarcadero's RAD?

Tags: software-development, ide, programming, rad

Embarcadero IDEs are very convenient. For instance if you click on a button located on a form then RAD automatically generates 'onclick' function in the code.
Are there any other IDE's or RAD's that have such feature? Besides Embarcadeo's and Lazarus?
The langauge isn't important.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) has a UI editor which does exactly that. The default method being generated depends on the UI element, but for buttons it's the `<buttonname>_Click()` method.

Language: C#

UI technology: WinForms

[image: Screenshot of designer and generated code]

UI technology: WPF

[image: Screenshot of designer and generated code]

The community edition of Visual Studio is free, so you can download and use it to check if this is what you need. It's Microsoft and works on Windows.

Comment: not only Visual Studio but other MS solutions such as VBA in MS Office also supports generating events automatically